# Replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu and retain data on disk drives

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7

I have created the bootable usb to install ubuntu on my system. However I want to remove my current Windows 7 OS  which is installed in the C Drive. Is there any way to retain the data in the D and E drives after completely replacing Windows 7 with Ubuntu?

Comment: This is not a programming question. That said, if you only format your C:\drive, other drives should remain unchanged... Now if you ask this question, I would ask why you want to move to Ubuntu as you don't seem to be a power user (no offence)

Answer (score 2):

If you do not choose to format the data in D and E drives they will retain if you change the OS . However the contents of C drive will be lost .